# Excel string search multimatch data retrieve

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize for my rusty english in advance.

I have an excel spreadsheet that has the following columns : url , visited date and time , and visit counts . In these columns there's so much information , some often repeated , such as " www.facebook.com " is repeated but with different dates and number of visits. What I'm trying to do in other Excel spreadsheet , is looking for a word in the url column, such as " Amazon " and next to that column shows the sum of the number of visits using data from the column "visit counts" for all "Amazon" matches.

Any idea on how to do this task using formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use Wild cards in a SUMIF() function:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*" & E2 & "*",C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue is that the urls, an example, for the word "facebook" appears like this https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id, some times like this https://www.facebook.com/ajax/pagelet/generic.php/, not just www.facebook.com =)

Comment: So you obviously did not try the formula.  It does not matter what else is attached as long as `facebook` is one of the words.